# Gmail SMTP not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, authentication, smtp, actionmailer

I am using the Gmail SMTP service to send email notifications from a web application (Ruby on Rails with Action Mailer for TLS support), but it stopped working a few weeks ago.  The initial failure was an authentication failure, but upon adding the domain to the login process (had not been needed for 5 years prior) I was able to get through, but the emails were never actually sent.  Below is a log from the SMTP server session:

```
-> "220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP y129sm117362qka.33 - gsmtp\r\n"  
<- "EHLO domain.com\r\n"  
-> "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [142.105.179.202]\r\n"  
-> "250-SIZE 35882577\r\n"  
-> "250-8BITMIME\r\n"  
-> "250-STARTTLS\r\n"  
-> "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n"  
-> "250-PIPELINING\r\n"  
-> "250-CHUNKING\r\n"  
-> "250 SMTPUTF8\r\n"  
<- "STARTTLS\r\n"  
-> "220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS\r\n"  
<- "EHLO domain.com\r\n"  
-> "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [142.105.179.202]\r\n"  
-> "250-SIZE 35882577\r\n"  
-> "250-8BITMIME\r\n"  
-> "250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH\r\n"  
-> "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n"  
-> "250-PIPELINING\r\n"  
-> "250-CHUNKING\r\n"  
-> "250 SMTPUTF8\r\n"  
<- "AUTH PLAIN AG5vcmVwbHlAYnJpZ2h0c2t5c29mdC5jb20AZm9ySGltOTIyN0Mz\r\n"  
-> "235 2.7.0 Accepted\r\n"  
<- "MAIL FROM:<noreply@domain.com>\r\n"  
-> "250 2.1.0 OK y129sm117362qka.33 - gsmtp\r\n"  
<- "RCPT TO:<user@domain.com>\r\n"  
-> "250 2.1.5 OK y129sm117362qka.33 - gsmtp\r\n"  
<- "DATA\r\n"  
-> "354  Go ahead y129sm117362qka.33 - gsmtp\r\n"  
writing message from String  
wrote 673 bytes  
-> "250 2.0.0 OK 1461203109 y129sm117362qka.33 - gsmtp\r\n"  
<- "QUIT\r\n"  
-> "221 2.0.0 closing connection y129sm117362qka.33 - gsmtp\r\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to allow less secure access to your Gmail account, follow these steps:

> 1. Go to the "Less secure apps" section in My Account.
> 2. Next to "Access for less secure apps," select Turn on. (Note to Google Apps users: This setting is hidden if your administrator has
>      locked less secure app account access.)

Source: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en